# What is this insect? (Location: Bangkok, Thailand; found on a rambutan; size: 8 mm long, 4 mm wide; color: black)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What is this insect? (Location: Bangkok, Thailand; found on a rambutan; size: 8 mm long, 4 mm wide; color: black)

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the rambutan:

[image]

Videos:

- https://youtu.be/WwB0B_PdOT8
- https://youtu.be/0DZ8nXcJIkI